# string manipulation without awk or sed

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep, cut

any help on this problem is appreciated
I have a text file with the following format

We can safely assume that the names are always three characters long, profession 7 characters and salary 5 characters
The varaibles come from user input and not as a parameters.

```
BobJanitor20000
TedBuilder30000
NedFighter25000
KitTeacher40000
```

I ask the user for a name input and another input whether to display occupation or Salary

If the user enters "Ted" and chooses salary, the output should be

```
Ted 30000
```

The program must also take into account partial name matches, "ed" and salary should output

```
Ted 30000
Ned 25000
```

I know `cut` and `grep` can get me the relavent lines but how do I create the output I want?

Comment: Are the name *always* 3 characters long? And can the script accept the values as parameters: `/blah/script Ted salary` or must they be read by the stdin?

Comment: yes, assume that the names are always three characters long, profession 7 characters and salary 5 characters: varaibles come from user input and not as a parameters.

Comment: can't use awk, sed or any other string utilities, updated OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a script that works for a name search. I'm using a **here document** (aka heredoc) instead of an external file to deliver the list to the while loop so that it's all contained in this file for ease of reading. You can expand it as you wish.

Read `man bash` for information on **builtin commands**, (and search the manual for things I have made bold) I'm using,

- **Substring Expansion** to get the parts of the line
- **Regular Expression** matching to find the match =~
- **[[**...]] to return a **conditional** value (0 or 1) depending on internal expression

Heres the script:

```
read -p "Input Name: " SearchName
while read line 
do
  Name=${line:0:3}
  Job=${line:3:7}
  Salary=${line:10:5}
  [[ $Name =~ $SearchName ]] && echo $Name $Salary
done << "end--"
BobJanitor20000
TedBuilder30000
NedFighter25000
end--

user@machine:~/tmp$ bash manipvar.sh 
Input Name: ed
Ted 30000
Ned 25000
user@machine:~/tmp$
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ grep -F ed file|fold -w 5|fold -w 3|grep -E '^[[:upper:]]..|^[0-9]'|paste -sd ' \0\n' -
Ted 30000
Ned 25000
```

Or:

```
$ cut -c 1-3,11- file | grep -F ed | fold -w 3 | paste -sd ' \0\n' -
Ted 30000
Ned 25000
```

Or (assuming GNU `grep`):

```
$ grep -oE '^.{3}|.{5}$' file | paste -sd ' \n' - | grep -F ed
Ted 30000
Ned 25000
```

You could also do (assuming a shell with process-substitution support) something like:

```
separate() {
  fold -w 1 -- "$@" |
    paste -sd '\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\n' - |
    sort -k 1,1
}

join <(separate file | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | grep -F ed
      ) <(separate file) | cut -d ' ' -f 1,3
```

Comment: `cut -c4-10 --complement file`

Comment: @Costas, only with GNU `cut`. That would be sacrificing portability to cosmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming separation is based on capital letter.

with SED

name + salary

```
sed -e "/${NamePart}.*[A-Z].*/ !d" -e 's/\([A-Z][a-z]*\)[A-Z][a-z]*\([0-9]*\)/\1 \2/' YourData.file
```

name + occupation

```
sed -e "/${NamePart}.*[A-Z].*/ !d" -e 's/\([A-Z][a-z]*\)\([A-Z][a-z]*\)[0-9]*/\1 \2/' YourData.file
```

Comment: hello, not allowed to use sed, awk or any other string utilities. And separation is based on predetermined length like name being 3 characters, profession being 6 and salary being 5

Comment: Is this some type of homework? In that case, I suppose it has a solution. I think the easiest way is using awk, sed or cut but if you can't use these tools...

Comment: you can use cut, just not awk or sed. And yes it is homework

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405611/extracting-first-two-characters-of-a-string-shell-scripting

Answer (score 1):

Use this (pure bash) script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# make the search case insensitive
shopt -s nocasematch
unset a; declare -A a

# read the name and save it in $name
read -p "Enter the Name: " name

# read the salary or profession and save it in $type
select type in salary profession;
do
  # loop trough the file
  while read l; do
    # characters 0 to 3 are the name
    n=${l:0:3}
    # the profession and the salary
    a["profession"]="${l:3:7}"
    a["salary"]="${l:10:5}"
    # if the name matches print the selected type
    [[ $n =~ $name ]] && echo "$n ${a[$type]}"
  done <file # the input file
  exit
done
```

---

The output:

```
$ ./script
Enter the Name: ed
1) salary
2) profession
#? 1
Ted 30000
Ned 25000
$ ./script
Enter the Name: ted
1) salary
2) profession
#? 2
Ted Builder
$ ./script
Enter the Name:
1) salary
2) profession
#? 2
Bob Janitor
Ted Builder
Ned Fighter
Kit Teacher
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
$ echo `grep -oe '^...\|[0-9]\{5\}' filename` | grep -oe '.\{9,10\}$\?' | grep ed
Ted 30000 
Ned 25000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that works kinda backwards:

```sh
xargs -I{} -n1      \
    expr {}\ {} : '[^0-9]*\(.* .ed\).*'
```

`expr` is handed two copies of each line back-to-back and divided by a space as its first argument. Like:

```
expr 'TedBuilder20000 TedBuilder20000' : '[^0-9]*\(.* .ed\).*'
```

And so its matched returns - if any - are *`Salary`* then *`Name`*:

```sh
printf %s\\n BobJanitor20000 TedBuilder30000 \
             NedFighter25000 KitTeacher40000 |
xargs -I{} -n1      \
    expr {}\ {} : '[^0-9]*\(.* .ed\).*'
```

---

```
30000 Ted
25000 Ned
```

This works, though:

```sh
xargs sh -c <input  '
      for a do case $a in (?ed*) ! :; esac  ||
            printf  %-4.3s${a##*[!0-9]}\\n "$a"
      done' ''
```

---

```
Ted 30000
Ned 25000
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here is a POSIX solution using neither `grep` nor `cut` :

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -

while IFS= read -r line; do
    name=${line%[A-Z]*} # remove smallest suffix beginning with uppercase
    occ=${line#???} # remove first 3 characters
    occ=${occ%?????} # remove last 5 characters
    salary=${line##*[!0-9]} # remove largest prefix ending with a non-digit
    case $name in
        *$1*)
            if [ "$2" = occupation ]; then
                printf '%s %s\n' "$curr_name" "$curr_occ"
            else
                printf '%s %s\n' "$curr_name" "$curr_salary"
            fi
    esac
done
```